# if statement doesn't check the condition

Tags: java, if-statement

Here is my problem, the if statement doesn't show the messagedialog when i don't insert anything in the inputdialog, but when i use != to compare the condition, it showup, why is this? as i know != mean not equal and == is equal

> ```
>     String firstName = "";
>     String lastName = "";
>
>     firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your first name");
>
>     if (firstName == "") {
>         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Don't leave it blank!");
>     } else
>     {
>         lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your last name");
>     }
>
>     String msg = "Hello " + firstName + lastName + "!";
>     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
> ```

Comment: Yep, you're right -- Java's obviously broken.  Has noting to do with attempting to compare strings with `==`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the most common mistakes in java. String require a `.equals()` rather than an `==`.

Wrong:

```
if (str == "foo") {

}
```

Right:

```
if ("foo".equals(str)) { // done in this order to avoid NPE

}
```

Comment: Then accept this answer, and we are all done here :D

Comment: still 4 minute to accept the answer, dunno why :(

Comment: I think there is some time restraint on accepting, couldn't tell you why. But do it when you can, and happy coding mate :D.